# Code not working. I am trying to click an element on a page with its id number but i cant

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to click an element on a page by using its ID from the HTML code. The ID of this button is "input-optionXXX" where XXX is a 3 digit number between 100 and 400. I want the python code to run through the HTML code on the page and find out what the 3 digit number (between 100 and 400) is so it can click on it. Any help?

```
a = list(range(100,400))
for i in a:
    if EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, f'input-option{str(i)}')):
        driver.find_element_by_id(f'input-option{i}').click()
        print(i)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karim\Desktop\b1.py", line 64, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id(f'input-option{i}').click()
  File "C:\Users\karim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\karim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\karim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\karim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="input-option100"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=xxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

Comment: For you to know what is EC => from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Comment: Sorry, `code not working` is not a diagnosis. Are there any symptoms? Can you run this code on a page where you know for certain what the 3 digit number should be?

Comment: line 64, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id(f'input-option{i}').click()

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="input-option100"]"}

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: it seems like its trying to find input-option100 instead of runing from 100 to 400 to see which works

Comment: i know that when i run it on the specific page i have open it should stop at 327 (input-option327)

Comment: So, what's the difference between: `EC.presence_of_element_located(..)` and `driver.find_element_by_id(..)`? They both seem like they should be testing for the presence of something.

Comment: when i put `EC.presence_of_element_located(..)` i was checking if it can find that certain element which it should, then after it does, it should click on it. So i wrote `driver.find_element_by_id(f'input-option{i}').click()`

Comment: Well, I can see what code you have written, I just don't know what either method does.

Comment: `driver` allows me to interact with elements on the HTML code of a page. it was coded in the beginning of my code as `from selenium import webdriver`
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try...except block:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

for i in range(100, 400):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id(f'input-option{i}').click()
        print(i)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine which ids are present, then:

```python
for i in range(100, 400):
    # The following might return an empty list but should not throw an exception:
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_id(f'input-option{i}')
    if elements:
        elements[0].click()
        print(i)
```